# How do i save my tool arrangement at the top of arcmap when i close it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, toolbar

When I close an arcmap project and then reopen it, even though I save the mxd, the toolbar arrangement is not the way I left it. Is there a setting or some way to save my toolbar locations?

Answer (score 5):

This is a quirk of Esri, it used to be the other way around. By default it will save all customization in *only* the current document, to change this open the menu customize::customize mode..

[image]

Turn off the checks indicated by the arrows to make ArcMap save to your Normal.mxt.

Please note that any open instances of ArcMap will write to the normal *on exit* so ensure that this is the only ArcMap open (catalog and scene don't count in this case) then exit ArcMap to make the settings permanent.